# How to create "go to mailbox" link in an html page?

Tags: html

I am creating a confirmation page that says "a verification email has been sent to your mailbox [foo@bar.com], please click `<here>` to check your email".

The question is how to create the link at `<here>` so that when a user click on it, it will load the default mail client (including Gmail)?

Comment: I would like to know how the browser will know which is the _default_ mail client? I thought it was possible to play with email clients like Outlook, Thunderbird etc. but is it possible to set a default client like gmail, yahoomail, etc??

Comment: @MaitreyaDwaipayan yes, it's possible (depending upon the OS), to register gmail as the default email client.

Comment: @steveax: Thanks for the response. Let me check how!!!

Comment: @MaitreyaDwaipayan see: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966

Comment: An aside, <here> is terrible linked text. Much better would be: <check your email>.

Answer (score 2):

There's simply no reliable way to launch the user's mail reading client from HTML.

As has been pointed out, you *could* craft a `mailto` link, but all that will do is load the mail *sending* application that the user has selected for that browser.  Applications are able to register themselves as able to handle `mailto` links, but those applications are not necessarily the same applications that are going to receive mail.  For example, you can ask Gmail to take over `mailto` links in many browsers.

Even then, consider that the user might not be using a desktop mail client to read their mail.  They could be on a mobile device, or not using their normal computer, or could use a webmail interface.

Simply telling the user to read their mail should be enough instruction for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I simply parse the domain from the input email, like @gmail.com, then I have a dictionary of most popular emails, like for gmail its mail.google.com. Same for others, if the users email is not in my dictionary, I simply point to mail..com and pray it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@something.com" >Your text</a>
```

Comment: This will open the mail client that has asked to handle `mailto` links, which can be an entirely different thing than the normal mail client.

Comment: Unless explicitly changed the mailto client is the same as the default mail client

Comment: But more importantly, it creates a new email message. What percentage of users would be annoyed by that? I know I would.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to implement this on a per-platform basis, depending on the user's email domain. So of course you wouldn't be able to have the "Go to Mailbox" button work for every single user email, but you should be able to support some of the most popular email providers.

I haven't been able to find a ready made list of providers and their corresponding URLs, but here are the few that I've found. I will update the list if I come across more in the future.

Also be warned that the email providers are free to change these at any time, so these links may stop working in the future.

- Gmail: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=email@domain.com (If not signed in → goes to currently signed in mailbox)
- Outlook: https://outlook.office.com/mail/email@domain.com (If not signed in → shows error)