# how to open mailbox itself thru html link (and not a new email)

Tags: email

How to enforce any link (html or anything else also) to open the mailbox, or least open the default email client where user can enter credentials.

Like for example, user clicks on "myEmails" link and it opens the user's inbox.

I have checked for "mailto" and it opens a new email, but I want to open the mailbox/inbox of the mail client.

Also, I have gone thru the following question, which is very relevant to what I want, but there are no right answers there.

[How to create "go to mailbox" link in an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928015/how-to-create-go-to-mailbox-link-in-an-html-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create "go to mailbox" link in an html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928015/how-to-create-go-to-mailbox-link-in-an-html-page)

Comment: Agree, and i have made the reference to original question also. This question is like an extension to the original question, which had remain almost un-answered.

Comment: Check the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11928109/1423876) from Charles. He gives exact answer. Web page doesn't suppose interaction with local software.