# HTML/Javascript code to Open Email App Inbox from a Webpage

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I have been trying to set a button that will take users to their email inbox once clicked but the only option i know is mailto which will create a message.

But in my case I want user email app to be opened after clicking on the button/link.

Please anyone with a good solution

I have tried `<a href="mailto:">Button</a>` but it open compose page instead of email app inbox.

Comment: Creating a new email is the only method of interaction with the default mail client on the front-end. You can't directly open that program.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928015/how-to-create-go-to-mailbox-link-in-an-html-page

Comment: If the email app is a webmail system (e.g. Gmail, or Outlook.com) you can just make a regular hyperlink e.g. `<a href="https://mail.google.com">Email</a>`